# iOS shortcuts rename file

Tags: ios, automation, shortcuts-app

I have an iOS shortcut which converts a photo to JPEG and resizes it, asks where to save and for the filename. There are two oddities, however:

1. The filename gets the .jpeg extension twice (I never type it)
2. If I use a dot in the filename, it chops off the filename there.

So a request to name as `scan of receipt £4.75` comes out as `scan of receipt £4.jpeg.jpeg`.

This seems somewhat buggy, unless I’m doing something stupid?

Here’s a screenshot of the workflow. The need to save the file *then* rename it afterwards seems odd but I can’t see an all-in-one "Save As".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. I'm using iOS 15.1.

Comment: My workaround has been to use Save action instead of Rename and set the new name at Subpath option.